# c reading a text file into array line by line and print them

Tags: c#, c, arrays, file

I have the following C# code snippet

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt");
for(int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
```

Can you help me to convert it to C?

Thanks!

Comment: For info, that isn't really reading "line by line" - it reads everything at once... but that is beside the point...

Comment: You should probably show what you have done so far to get some help.

Comment: I have my program perfectly working in C#, and I am very new to C. What I am doing is getting an ascii file consisting of 3 million files, which every line consists of three floating points separated by space... And I have another file which is approximately of the same size. They are running in outer and inner loops, so it is in total 3million*3million,......

Comment: If it works perfectly in C#, why are you converting it to C? And why are you doing it without already knowing C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use Ansi Standard C, you'll need `fopen`, `fgets`, and `printf` to do what you want.

Here's [a tutorial that does almost exactly what you want](http://irc.essex.ac.uk/www.iota-six.co.uk/c/i2_feof_fgets_fread.asp).

Comment: C is case sensitive, so those all need to be in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) and [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) functions.

`fgets` in particular will read until a newline character is reached, so it is perfect for reading in text files a line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

the process should work pretty much as expected:

Open the file, figure out the encoding (ReadAllLines does that for you) read the input with the guessed encoding, recode it into your target format - which will probably be UTF16 - and print it to stdout...

Answer (score 0):

Just for what it's worth, if you're just copying the data from one stream to another, there's no need to worry about doing it line by line -- the lines are determined by new-line characters (or carriage returns and/or carriage return/line feed combos) in the data.

If you simply copy the data through without changing it, the lines will be preserved. To maximize speed, you probably want to open the file in binary mode, and use fread/fwrite to copy fairly large chunks (e.g. 4 megabytes) of data at a time.

Comment: I have my program perfectly working in C#, and I am very new to C. What I am doing is getting an ascii file consisting of 3 million files, which every line consists of three floating points separated by space... And I have another file which is approximately of the same size. They are running in outer and inner loops, so it is in total 3million*3million,....

Comment: @asel: and what are you doing with that cross-product?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in simple way with C++.

```
ifstream input("test.in");
string line;
while(getline(input, line)) {
  //Your code for the current line
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a mistake. You declare a `string line` but then call `getline(input, s)`. Perhaps `s == line` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `fgets` invites tricky edge cases:

- What if a line's length is greater than the size of a fixed-width buffer?
- What if the file doesn't end with a newline?
- What if the last line fits exactly in the buffer without causing the end-of-file status to be set?

On my blog, I posted an [example of how to do it robustly with `fgets`](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2010/02/reading-variable-length-lines-from-text.html).