# Retrieving total line numbers in a file

Tags: c, file, text

can someone show me how to get the total number of lines in a text file in programming language C?

Comment: Is performance a factor? How large are the files likely to be?

Comment: your previous question did not help him? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910618/c-reading-a-text-file-into-array-line-by-line-and-print-them

Comment: it will contain 3 million lines, every line consist of three floating points separated by space, it is Triangulated Irregular Network file generated from LIDAR LAS file.

Comment: I'm assuming that because they are floats, that the lines don't have fixed width? If they did there would be a very simple and fast solution.

Comment: This smells suspiciously like class work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is one approach:

```
FILE* myfile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
int ch, number_of_lines = 0;

do 
{
    ch = fgetc(myfile);
    if(ch == '\n')
        number_of_lines++;
} while (ch != EOF);

// last line doesn't end with a new line!
// but there has to be a line at least before the last line
if(ch != '\n' && number_of_lines != 0) 
    number_of_lines++;

fclose(myfile);

printf("number of lines in test.txt = %d", number_of_lines);
```

Comment: This function gives false results, because the loop is exited on `ch != EOF` and then the value of `ch` is tested with `ch != '\n'` which is always true, since at this point `ch` equals `EOF`.
The function incorrectly returns one more line if the file ends with a `\n` character.
If the file is empty or if it does not end with `\n` the function returns the expected number of lines.
A correct solution would check the last character before the `EOF`.

Answer (score -5):

A "not by a project manager" solution

```
system("wc profile.dat > no.lines"); 
FILE *pfile = fopen("no.lines", "r");
int lines; 
fscanf(pfile, "%d", &lines); 
system("rm no.lines");
```

Comment: This is a really unproductive answer. Also, you are digging up a question from 2009

Comment: This answer assumes using a specific OS.