# Using fscanf to scan contents of a text document into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I need to scan the contents of a text document, namely;

```
77, 66, 80, 81
40,  5, 35, -1
51, 58, 62, 34
 0, -1, 21, 18
61, 69, 58, 49
81, 82, 90, 76
44, 51, 60, -1
64, 63, 60, 66
-1, 38, 41, 50
69, 80, 72, 75
```

into an array, with each number in its own block, and then read each block to identify what the contents are. I feel like I have the processing part complete, but I can't work out how to allocate a number to a block in the array. Here is what I have so far;

```
int main()
{
    FILE * marks;
    marks = fopen("marks.txt", "r");
    int marksArray[4][10], x, y, greaterThan70 = 0, between60and69 = 0, between50and59 = 0, between40and49 = 0, lessThan39 = 0, notSubmitted = 0;
    //Scanning in the contents
    while ((fscanf(marks, "%d", &marksArray[x][y])) != EOF)
    {
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    //Processing the array
    for(x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            if(marksArray[x][y] == -1)
            {
                notSubmitted++;
            }
            else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 0 && marksArray[x][y] <= 39)
            {
                lessThan39++;
            }
            else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 40 && marksArray[x][y] <= 49)
            {
                between40and49++;
            }
            else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 50 && marksArray[x][y] <= 59)
            {
                between50and59++;
            }
            else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 60 && marksArray[x][y] <= 69)
            {
                between60and69++;
            }
            else
            {
                greaterThan70++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("The number of marks greater than 70 was %d", greaterThan70);
    printf("The number of marks between than 60 and 69 was %d", between60and69);
    printf("The number of marks between than 50 and 59 was %d", between50and59);
    printf("The number of marks between than 40 and 49 was %d", between40and49);
    printf("The number of marks less than 39 was %d", lessThan39);
    printf("The number of coursework submissions not handed in was %d", notSubmitted);
}
```

Comment: this line: int marksArray[4][10] has an error, as the ROW is first, followed by the COLUMN.  so (given the example file contents) the line should be: int marksArray[10][4]  then the limit values on the 'for' loops for 'x' and 'y' need to be updated to match.

Comment: when reading the array values, the code should only increment the ROW count (x) when the COLUMN count (y) reaches its' limit

Comment: since the code is doing nothing with the contents of the array, as a whole, it might be better to have only a single int variable, read into the int variable, then process that single value, then loop to read the next input into that single variable.

Comment: this line: while ((fscanf(marks, "%d", &marksArray[x][y])) != EOF) has a problem in that a ',' is not white space.  so probably will fail to read past the first int value.  Suggest reading a line at a time (fgets) then parsing the line using something like strtok(..., ",") and atoi() to extract the successive integers, (this would also allow for variant number of integers in a line from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(fscanf(marks, "%d", &marksArray[x][y])
```

Chokes on the first comma. You'll want something more like:

```
(fscanf(marks, "%d, ", &marksArray[x][y])
```

The comma and white space (which also eats new lines) are important. Except that your last character doesn't end with a comma, so that won't quite work.

Yeah, and this:

```
while ((fscanf(marks, "%d", &marksArray[x][y])) != EOF)
{
    x++;
    y++;
}
```

If it worked, it would walk through the array in this pattern:

```
X000
0X00
00X0
000X
```

What you want is something more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
FILE * marks;
marks = fopen("in.txt", "r");
int marksArray[4][10], x, y, greaterThan70 = 0, between60and69 = 0, between50and59 = 0, between40and49 = 0, lessThan39 = 0, notSubmitted = 0;
//Scanning in the contents
//No need for EOF if you know the size ahead of time
for(y=0; y<10; y++)
{
  for(x=0; x<3; x++)
  {
    fscanf(marks, "%d, ", &marksArray[x][y]);
  }      
  //To deal with the annoying lack of comma at the end of the line
  //Be wary of EoL variance, the difference between \n and \r\n, bloody windows...
  fscanf(marks, "%d\n", &marksArray[x][y]);
}

//Processing the array
for(x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        if(marksArray[x][y] == -1)
        {
            notSubmitted++;
        }
        else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 0 && marksArray[x][y] <= 39)
        {
            lessThan39++;
        }
        else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 40 && marksArray[x][y] <= 49)
        {
            between40and49++;
        }
        else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 50 && marksArray[x][y] <= 59)
        {
            between50and59++;
        }
        else if(marksArray[x][y] >= 60 && marksArray[x][y] <= 69)
        {
            between60and69++;
        }
        else
        {
            greaterThan70++;
        }
        break;
    }
}
printf("The number of marks greater than 70 was %d\n", greaterThan70);
printf("The number of marks between than 60 and 69 was %d\n", between60and69);
printf("The number of marks between than 50 and 59 was %d\n", between50and59);
printf("The number of marks between than 40 and 49 was %d\n", between40and49);
printf("The number of marks less than 39 was %d\n", lessThan39);
printf("The number of coursework submissions not handed in was %d\n", notSubmitted);
}
```

And don't listen to that guy `C` is awesome and the right language for every problem. Ever.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the response! The code seems the work for the most part, however it seems to only read the first line of numbers, ie. 77, 66, 80, 81. Any idea as to why it might not increment down the y axis?

Comment: @SexRobomb. Yeah, it's the break in the for loop at the bottom. It breaks out of the loop before it gets a chance to, you know, loop. Just get rid of it and it works fine.   Also, vote and accept. I covet these rep points, lying awake at night wondering how to acquire more. My prrrreeeeeesiouses.

Comment: Haha, thanks, got it sorted! You earned those precious rep points :)

Answer (score 0):

First, are you really sure that you can't do this in C++ ([ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/))([getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)) ?

Secondly, if you **must** do it in C, then you should look into the file and count the number of lines and the number of comma on each line. To get the total [number of line in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910724/c-retrieving-total-line-numbers-in-a-file)

You can then iterate again the file, line by line and count the number of comma ( if there is not always 4 numbers on each line like in your question ).