# How to declare and fill a global integer array of unknown size in C

Tags: c, arrays, integer, global

I need to read in an unknown number of integers from a text file (one on each line) and store them in a global array so that I can sort them on different threads.

My thought was to declare (globally) `int numberOfValuesToSort;`, then set this by making a quick pass through the file and counting the number of lines (I have this part working just fine).

I will also declare globally `int * unsortedValues;` and `int * sortedValues;` (I am not sure if that is the correct format though, perhaps I need two stars?)

Then, my hope is to allocate the appropriate number of integer slots (`numberOfValuesToSort`) in each of the two arrays, so that I can fill the `unsortedValues` array and then sort it into `sortedValues`.

I tried the approach below, but get gibberish numbers when I print, so I know I am doing something incorrectly:

```
/* Allocate the appropriate amount of space in our arrays */
unsortedValues = malloc(numberOfValuesToSort * sizeof(int));
sortedValues   = malloc(numberOfValuesToSort * sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValuesToSort; i++){
    fscanf(myfile, "%d", &unsortedValues[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValuesToSort; i++) {
    printf("Number is: %d\n\n", unsortedValues[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**

After some printing, I have noticed that the size of `unsortedValues` is 8, whereas (for the test case I am using), the `numberOfValuesToSort` is only 6. Including the following code seems to succeed at setting each spot in the array to zero, so my output is now always = 0 (instead of the gibberish I was seeing before). However, the difference in size is a red flag, as well as the fact that I am still seeing all zeros instead of the numbers from my input file.

```
printf("Size of unsortedValues = %lu\nnumberOfValuesToSort = %d\n",
    sizeof(unsortedValues), numberOfValuesToSort);

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(unsortedValues); i++){
    unsortedValues[i] = 0;
    printf("unsortedValues[%d] = %d\n", i, unsortedValues[i]);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Size of unsortedValues = 8
numberOfValuesToSort = 6
unsortedValues[0] = 0
unsortedValues[1] = 0
unsortedValues[2] = 0
unsortedValues[3] = 0
unsortedValues[4] = 0
unsortedValues[5] = 0
unsortedValues[6] = 0
unsortedValues[7] = 0

unsortedValues[0] = 0
unsortedValues[1] = 0
unsortedValues[2] = 0
unsortedValues[3] = 0
unsortedValues[4] = 0
unsortedValues[5] = 0
```

Comment: Can you please choose one language?  The way to do this in C++ is completely different to the way it is done in C.  It _looks_ like you want C.  You need dynamic allocation.  Look in to `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

Comment: My apologies, I thought putting C in the title would make it clear. I have removed the C++ tag.

Comment: This call looks strange to me `&unsortedValues[i]` I think what you want is `unsortedValues+i`

Comment: @TonyRuth The two are equivalent.  Many prefer `&unsortedValues[i]` over pointer arithmetic.

Comment: not likely the problem but you should check the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Can you set each element of the array to zero before scanning. This will tell you if the strange numbers you see are because you are scanning strange number, or if the strange numbers are random gibberish that existed where the array was allocated and nothing is being scanned.

Comment: `sizeof` is the size of the pointer not the number of elements. Assuming you're running on a 64-bit machine pointers are 64-bits or 8 chars.

Comment: Your troubles are due to a lack of understanding of very basic concepts of C and programming in general.  I suggest to read one of the many beginner's manuals on C programming.  In particular, take a look at chapters dealing with initialization, sizeof, dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's often better to use an actual data structure for this kind of thing, since you're going to need to store the length somewhere along with the data. Also if you're sorting on different threads, you're going to need to synchronize access, and if you use an actual data structure you can put a mutex in there for that purpose.

Here's an example of a dynamically resizable array to do the job:

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "darray.h"

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    darray arr = darray_create();

    FILE * fp = fopen("numbers.dat", "r");
    if ( !fp ) {
        perror("couldn't open data file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ( 1 ) {
        char buffer[BUFSIZE];
        int value;

        if ( !fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, fp) ) {
            break;
        }

        if ( sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value) != 1 ) {
            break;
        }

        darray_append(arr, value);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    const size_t len = darray_length(arr);
    printf("Length of array: %zu\n", len); 

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
        printf("%3zu: %d\n", i, darray_get(arr, i));
    }

    darray_destroy(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

`darray.h`:

```
#ifndef DARRAY_H
#define DARRAY_H

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct darray * darray;

darray darray_create(void);
void darray_destroy(darray arr);
size_t darray_length(darray arr);
void darray_append(darray arr, const int data);
void darray_set(darray arr, const size_t index, const int data);
int darray_get(darray arr, const size_t index);
void darray_shrink(darray arr);

#endif      /*  DARRAY_H  */
```

`darray.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "darray.h"

#define INIT_ELEMS 16

struct darray {
    int * data;
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
};

darray darray_create(void)
{
    struct darray * new_arr = malloc(sizeof *new_arr);
    if ( !new_arr ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for darray");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_arr->data = malloc(INIT_ELEMS * sizeof *new_arr->data);
    if ( !new_arr->data ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for darray elements");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_arr->length = 0;
    new_arr->capacity = INIT_ELEMS;
    return new_arr;
}

void darray_destroy(darray arr)
{
    free(arr->data);
    free(arr);
}

size_t darray_length(darray arr)
{
    return arr->length;
}

static void darray_reallocate(darray arr, const size_t new_size)
{
    arr->capacity = new_size;
    if ( arr->length > arr->capacity ) {
        arr->length = arr->capacity;
    }
    int * new_data = realloc(arr->data, arr->capacity);
    if ( !new_data ) {
        perror("couldn't reallocate memory for darray data");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    arr->data = new_data;
}

void darray_append(darray arr, const int data)
{
    if ( arr->length == arr->capacity ) {
        darray_reallocate(arr, arr->capacity * 2);
    }

    arr->data[arr->length++] = data;
}

void darray_set(darray arr, const size_t index, const int data)
{
    if ( index >= arr->length ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't set - index of %zu exceeds length of %zu\n",
                index, arr->length);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    arr->data[index] = data;
}

int darray_get(darray arr, const size_t index)
{
    if ( index >= arr->length ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get - index of %zu exceeds length of %zu\n",
                index, arr->length);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return arr->data[index];
}

void darray_shrink(darray arr)
{
    if ( arr->length != arr->capacity ) {
        darray_reallocate(arr, arr->length);
    }
}
```

with output:

```
paul@horus:~/Documents/src/sandbox/nsort$ cat numbers.dat
1432
9382
4211
482
55819
11
777
2881
33
6224
paul@horus:~/Documents/src/sandbox/nsort$ ./nsort
Length of array: 10
  0: 1432
  1: 9382
  2: 4211
  3: 482
  4: 55819
  5: 11
  6: 777
  7: 2881
  8: 33
  9: 6224
paul@horus:~/Documents/src/sandbox/nsort$
```

Note that you only have to make one pass through the input file this way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. By making an initial pass through the file to count the number of lines, I was causing successive calls to fscanf to begin at the end of the file and return `-1`.

What I needed to do was:

- Open the file
- Scan through it, counting the number of lines
- Allocate the appropriate amount of space in my array
- Seek back to the beginning of the file
- Scan through the file once more, this time reading the integers into my array
- Close the file

Here is my working code:

```
    /* Determine how many integers (one per line) the file holds */
/* From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910724/retrieving-total-line-numbers-in-a-file */
FILE * myfile = fopen(filename, "r");
int ch = 0;
do{
    ch = fgetc(myfile);
    if(ch == '\n'){ numberOfValuesToSort++; }
} while(ch != EOF);
/* Seek to the beginning of the file */
rewind(myfile);

/* Allocate the appropriate amount of space in our arrays */
unsortedValues = malloc(numberOfValuesToSort * sizeof(int));
sortedValues   = malloc(numberOfValuesToSort * sizeof(int));

/* Read through the file again, this time grabbing integers from it as we scan */
int i = 0;
while (!feof (myfile)) {
    /* Read an integer and insert it in the array unsortedValues */
    fscanf (myfile, "%d", &unsortedValues[i]);
    i++;
}
/* Close the file */
fclose(myfile);

/* Ensure we have filled the array with the correct values */
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValuesToSort; i++){
    printf("unsortedValues[%d] = %d\n", i, unsortedValues[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why go through the pointless hassle of opening the file again under a different handle, with the reopens and reallocations etc that involves? Just seek back to the beginning once you've got the size. All the guides I've seen on how to get file sizes have done this; it's a fundamental concept.

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. None of the examples I have looked at used that concept, but yes, that certainly sounds better! Thank you.

Comment: @underscore_d You were right. Much cleaner. I have updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, far better, isn't it? :-) Maybe I was lucky in the guides I chose to give attention to, heh. Also, I'm hypervigilant for this stuff at the moment, as I've been going through my current (C++) project and - although it worked fine - analysing it to remove unnecessary duplication of code (work for me) and checks/allocations/etc (work for the computer). A few facepalm moments along the way, too, haha.